# How can I add the main class to MANIFEST.MF for a Kotlin jar built with Bazel?

Tags: kotlin, bazel

I'm building a very simple jar with one main method. I've got the Kotlin rules working, and I can build the jar just fine:

```
kt_jvm_binary(
    name = "myapp",
    main_class = "MainKt",
    srcs = ["src/main/kotlin/Main.kt"]
)
```

However, that `main_class` argument doesn't add anything to the manifest to allow me to run the jar (I assume the one in the bazel-bin folder is the right one).

I've tried using a library then compiling it using the `java_binary` rule instead:

```
kt_jvm_library(
    name = "myapp_lib",
    srcs = ["src/main/kotlin/Main.kt"]
)

java_binary(
    name = "myapp",
    main_class = "MainKt",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    runtime_deps = [":myapp_lib"],
    deploy_manifest_lines = ["Main-Class: MainKt"]
)
```

Now I have two jars; myapp.jar which just has a manifest, and myapp_lib.jar which has the class file. Neither of them have a main class in the manifest, regardless of whether I include that `deploy_manifest_lines` argument or not.

How do I build my very simple jar with a main class that allows me to run it?

(Note that I will be working with desktops and TornadoFX, *not* Android.)

Comment: I don't know about Kotlin specifically, but in general there are two ways to run JVM binaries with bazel;

* `bazel run :myapp` should put everything (including a jar with a manifest) on the classpath and run it. You can run with `-s` and it should tell you what command line it's running, so you can inspect the classpath.

* Or you can build a "deploy jar" by building `bazel build :myapp_deploy.jar` which will make a fat jar with everything you need in a single jar, including the manifest.

Comment: @DanielWagner-Hall Fantastic, that works even with Kotlin and I can see where my Main-Class comment now appears twice! Please could you make that into an answer so I can upvote you? Bazel's pretty new and I think this advice will help a bunch of other people too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of things in Bazel aren't "magical", and this is an example.  The "main_class" isn't there to affect packaging, it's there to tell the bazel *_binary rule how to execute, so you can do `bazel run //path/to/my/binary:target` . It doesn't affect packaging.  That's up to you. You would add your own meta-inf information and make sure the `resources=` pulls in your packaging metadata.

Part of this is because Bazel doesn't (by default) make an "executable jar" but instead builds a wrapper script which you execute which invokes the jvm with the jar.

Your second example should work... you're not looking at the right jar. The jar that actually has all the deployment bits should be: `myapp_deploy.jar` which contains all the "upstream" deps' classes, plus any meta-inf stuff, all baked into a single jar.

Answer (score 3):

In general when building JVM targets in Bazel, each part of the classpath you may want may be put into different locations, so it's not always easy to predict where any particular part will end up.

If you want to run the binary and see it work, you can `bazel run :myapp` and it *should* work properly, with the manifest and such, from some jar on the classpath.

If you want to explore which different jars get created, and what the classpath looks like, the flag `-s` will output each command line that Bazel runs, and will show you what the classpath entries were so you can explore them. i.e. `bazel run -s :myapp`.

You can also generate a single "fat" jar containing the transitive classpath smooshed together into one file, by building the implicit "deploy-jar" target: `bazel build :myapp_deploy.jar` which should produce a file which will then work standalone.